# typeahead.js hint and highlight param not working with prefetch & remote

Tags: javascript, jquery, typeahead.js

I followed the instruction here to implement typeahead with bloodhound:
http://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/examples/#bloodhound

This is my html:

```
<div id="remote">
  <input class="typeahead" type="text" placeholder="Search for cast and directors"> 
</div>
```

This is my js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var castDirectors = new Bloodhound({
  datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('value'),
  queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
  prefetch: '../api/v1/search/people_typeahead',
  remote: '../api/v1/search/people_typeahead?q=%QUERY',
    dupDetector: function(remoteMatch, localMatch) {
        return remoteMatch.value === localMatch.value;
    }
});

castDirectors.initialize();

$('#remote .typeahead').typeahead(null, {
  name: 'cast-directors',
  displayKey: 'value',
  source: castDirectors.ttAdapter(),
    hint: false,
    highlight: true,
    templates: {
        empty: [
      '<div class="empty-message">',
      'No matching names',
      '</div>'
    ].join('\n'),
        suggestion: Handlebars.compile('<a id="typeahead" href="{{link}}"><p>{{value}}</p></a>')
    }       
});
});
```

however, even with hint set to false and highlight set to true, I'm still seeing hint and not getting highlights in the typeahead. What should I change?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try to place the hint, highlight and add also minLength: 1 instead of the first null, it should look like this:

```
$('#remote .typeahead').typeahead(
{
    hint: false,
    highlight: true,
    minLength: 1
},
{
  name: 'cast-directors',
  displayKey: 'value',
  source: castDirectors.ttAdapter(),

    templates: {
        empty: [
      '<div class="empty-message">',
      'No matching names',
      '</div>'
    ].join('\n'),
        suggestion: Handlebars.compile('<a id="typeahead" href="{{link}}"><p>{{value}}</p></a>')
    }       
});
```

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately the code for the [remote example](https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/examples/#remote) on the typeahead.js site doesn't use options in the call to the `typeahead()` function and a copy/paste will lead you into this problem.

As it was well pointed by [prsnca](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3644737/prsnca) you have to make sure to add these options in the first argument of the function.

#### No Highlight

```
$('#remote .typeahead').typeahead(null, {
  name: 'best-pictures',
  displayKey: 'value',
  source: bestPictures.ttAdapter()
});
```

#### Highlight

```
$('#remote .typeahead').typeahead(
  {
    hint: false,
    highlight: true,
    minLength: 1
  },
  {
    name: 'best-pictures',
    displayKey: 'value',
    source: bestPictures.ttAdapter()
  }
);
```